# Need advice on how to best deal with the storing/unboxing of different types in a list and what is more optimal in my case

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, c#-4.0

Lets say I wish to be able to render different view logic for two different types, both are store items/products that will be used in search result views etc. Ultimately I would want the objects ordered according to a price property which both have, but of course they are still different types so I wonder if it is possible to order different object types in a list by using a property value of the same type on each?

I have a `Product` type and `ProductCombo` type.

Is it more optimal to store them in the model class as such (Probably can't order them then):

```
public class
{

public List<Product> ProductList {get; set;}

public List<ProductCombo> ProductComboList {get; set;}

}
```

Or

```
public class
{

public List<object> StoreItems {get; set;}

}
```

If I use the above 2nd option I would of course have to unbox each object, get the type and decide what action to take for said type in the view. I think this is my best choice ? Considering that I would want to order the items in the `List<object>` by their decimal type price property.

Also another crude way to do it would be this I am guessing.

```
public class StoreItem
{
public Product product {get; set;}

public ProductCombo productCombo {get; set;}

public double itemPrice {get; set;} 

}
```

And then just store in `List<StoreItem>`
setting the itemPrice when doing a foreach on
each object returned from the database.

Comment: i think it all depends on what you are doing if you really want to stick with two list or you can create a new list like cart (i mean object cart that will contain information about cart) and add the need items from the list one and list two to the cart list and sort it based on the price value in the list

Comment: terminology alert: casting an object reference to a Product is only unboxing if Product is a struct, which it most likely is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not do something like this

```
public interface IPricedItem
{
    double Price { get; }
}

class Product : IPricedItem { ... }
class ProductCombo : IPricedItem { ... }

public class Whatever
{
    public List<IPricedItem> StoreItems { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest adding a common interface for the two types. You may then define all common properties on the interface to support sorting etc.

`List<IProduct>` would be your only collection.

Answer (score 3):

You should have an interface with methods for all of the functionality common among the two objects, and have a list typed to that interface.  The interface should probably extend comparable, so that they can have a compare method of comparing themselves to another instance of the interface.